# Device not compatible in google cloud test lab

Tags: android, apk, firebase-test-lab

I am testing my application apk on cloud test lab. It's working fine on some devices, but the other devices are showing:

```
Incompatible device/API level combination.
```

I am not getting what is the problem.
I attached an image below. How to solve these issues?

[image]

Comment: This is totally dump design from Google and wasting a lot of my time testing upload apk from Android Studio to Firebase test lab. The way they give you options is like putting ice-cream menu board saying you can mix multiple flavour but ends up telling you that you can't mix this with that...

Comment: This is so crazy! I'm having the same problem, in the picture we can see how a devices 21 is compatible but other is not, what? Are they trying to explain that device doesn't exist? Compare the nexus 5 lvl 21 with Moto E lvl 21

Answer (score 2):

Though the original question is a while ago the problem still exists: How can I find out which physical device can be combined with which api level in Firebase test lab.

AndroidStudio 3.3.2 allows to choose every combination and your tests fails with

> Skipped triggering the test execution: Incompatible device/OS combination

if the chosen combination is not valid.

The only way I've found is: Start a test in the Firebase console (in your browser). After (!) uploading your apk and test apk the UI brings up a list of available physical devices and the api levels usable on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore that messages because the test matrix was created with necessary configurations.
The physical Galaxy S4 has API level 19 and you can see in the second line right configuration. Other API levels not supported by S4 so Cloud Test Lab displayed a message for you.
You should care the situation when selected devices doesn't meet **all** selected API levels.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, its tell you that eg. Galaxy S4 has API level 19, and it could be tested with API 19. But, the same device, Galaxy S4 could not be tested on API level 21, 22 and the test is skipped.